# minted package doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: minted, windows

On my Windows 7 laptop with the MikTeX-21.6 installed, I needed to use the `minted` package which uses the Python's `Pygments` module so I've installed `Pygments-2.9.0` (the latest version) and it works perfectly (I've pygmented a basic `C` file with `pygmentize -l c -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge main.c` and its output is the same as the reference sample) The path of the `pygmentize.exe` is set correctly in the Windows path.

When I try to compile the following .tex file:

`xelatex.exe -shell-escape pygment_SAMPLE.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small]{c}
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
}  
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

it prompts :`\minted@apppathifexists=`

I enter `t` then it stops with:

```
! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.
```

The problem seems to revolve around those lines:

```
for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > pygment_SAMPLE.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> pygment_SAMPLE.aex
```

Windows 7's failure to correctly process this line or the way the Windows 7 handles the paths or file permissions inside the `minted` context.

In order to debug this problem I've tried uncommenting the line 775 at `minted.sty`

```
               % For debugging, uncomment: %%%%
this line -->  % \immediate\typeout{\minted@cmd}%
               % %%%%
```

But it had no effect. I guess the `minted.sty` must be rebuilt / reinstalled and  I don't know the internals of the `.tex` language.

I've posted this issue on the github issues page [Win 10 - Texlive Failed to find installed pygmentize #280](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/280) and there they've suggested that I post this issue on StackOverflow so here you are: How to make the `minted` work correctly on Windows 7? Note that this issue affects Windows 10, too.

#### Update with extra info:

After adding these into the `c:/Program Files/miktex-21.6/texmfs/config/miktex/config/miktex.ini`

```
ShellCommandMode = Restricted
AllowedShellCommands[] = miktex-bibtex
AllowedShellCommands[] = miktex-bibtex8
AllowedShellCommands[] = miktex-epstopdf
AllowedShellCommands[] = miktex-gregorio
AllowedShellCommands[] = miktex-kpsewhich
AllowedShellCommands[] = miktex-makeindex
AllowedShellCommands[] = bibtex
AllowedShellCommands[] = bibtex8
AllowedShellCommands[] = extractbb
AllowedShellCommands[] = findtexmf
AllowedShellCommands[] = gregorio
AllowedShellCommands[] = kpsewhich
AllowedShellCommands[] = makeindex
AllowedShellCommands[] = texosquery-jre8
AllowedShellCommands[] = pygmentize
```

`$ xelatex --restrict-write18 pygments_SAMPLE.tex -shell-escape`

brings up with the same prompt:

```
C:\Users\Lars
>set  /p x=C:\Program Files\python-3.5.0\Scripts\pygmentize.exe 0<nul: 1>>pygments.aex

C:\Users\Lars
>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>pygments.aex

C:\Users\Lars
>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>pygments.aex

\minted@apppathifexists=
```

and whatever I enter into the `\minted@apppathifexists=` doesn't matter it ends up with the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that the directory with the `pygmentize` executable is in your PATH (which you can edit under “Environment Variables” in System Properties > Advanced).  You will also need to run your TeX program with the `--shell-restricted` option and edit your `texmf.cnf` to allow this specific program to run, or else throw caution to the wind and run with `--shell-escape`.

The default `texmf.cnf` in TeX Live 2021 says that `pygmentize` is not declared in `shell_escape_commands` by default because of concerns about the security of its filter feature.  If you do want to change this, you would add

```
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
pygmentize,\
%
```

to the custom `texmf.cnf` in `texlive/YYYY/`, not the one in `texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/`.

On MikTeX, you probably instead want to run TeX wirh `--restrict-write18` and run `initexmf` to modify [`miktex.ini`](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex.ini.html).  You would want to add a new `AllowedShellCommands[] = pygmentize` line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There's no `texmf.cnf` in the Miktext installation folder but there is a `miktex.ini` as `c:/Program Files/miktex-21.6/texmfs/config/miktex/config/miktex.ini`  which have entries like `[Core]
LastUserMaintenance=1623612020` and `[Setup]
LastUserDiagnose=1623612025` where to enter the _specific program_ ? `pygmentize` is already in path.

Comment: I use TeX Live rather than MikTeX, but does a file search find a `texmf.cnf` anywhere?

Comment: I've already searched. No file named `texmf` with an extension of `.cnf` or `.ini` There are about 360 files with the extension `.ini` such as `xelatex.ini` `latex.ini` `latex209.ini` `tex.ini` `lualatex.ini` etc which makes it hard to decide which one to edit.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Okay, I think I found the instructions for MikTeX. I don’t have a copy to test, however.

Comment: Tried with the `--restrict-write18` and `--shell-restricted` and their combinations. No change in situation. I've added `AlloweShellCommands[] = pygmentize` under the [CORE] section in `miktex.ini` again no change in situtation. When I add the `shell_escape_commands = ...`  into `miktex.ini` it gives `error="invalid value definition" Segmentation fault` The miktex.ini doesn't accept such a value, it seems (Update: the `shell_escape_commands` belongs to the TeX Live not MiKTeX)

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Yes, that’s correct: you do not add `shell_escape_commands` to `miktex,ini`. That’s for a completely different file with a different format. Try updating your `miktex.ini` settings with `initexmf`. After that, `--restrict-write18` should work.

Comment: Updated the OP. Changing editing the `miktex.ini` and adding `--restrict-write18` option to the command-line has no effect upon the problem.